# Rails: Return all Parents with existing Child

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to find all users who have created at least one post, given:

**User**

```
has_many: posts
```

**Post**

```
belongs_to: user
```

I currently have `User.joins(:posts).distinct`

Comment: Down-voting without commenting is a vote to discourage activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`User.joins(:posts).uniq.all`.

This returns all users for which there exists at least one post (joins) and eliminates all duplicates (uniq).

Comment: That's the ticket. Any difference between .uniq and .distinct? (learning RoR methods every day) Is .all needed?

Comment: => I see they are aliased ;) Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @gr8scott06.  I am not much further down the RoR road than you (if at all).  You may be able to drop the `.all` - in my testing I did not notice a difference.